# How to receive continuous streamed screen capture to a browser using PHP?

Tags: php, webserver, video-streaming, html, screen-capture

What I am trying to achieve is this. I have a server that is running a http server application that is supposed to take screen capture of the system. I want to be able to open a webpage to my server and start to receive the streaming screen capture continuously and view it on my browser much like the IP Camera App for Android phones. I want to do this using PHP. Can it be done? If not, what should be my approach and technology should be used.

My webserver is Linux running http server application.

Any help, hints or clues will appreciated.

Comment: why not just use VNC?

Comment: I don't want to run any third-party program. I have looked into Go To My PC, Tight VNC and PCAnywhere. I am not trying to recreate or re-invent the wheel. I am looking for a simple solution where my user can view or get a quick update on their device smartphone, tablet, laptop, etc by opening their browser to a specific path or URL. My intention is to give more options later on but for now just the screen capture is good enough or at least that's what they want.

Comment: first you'll have to solve getting screen captures. consider that the webserver runs as an unprivileged user and would not have any access to the console's screen buffer.